# How can I properly type annotate an expression that builds a List of Sequences?

Tags: python, mypy

I want to build a list that contains tuples or lists of strings.  I want:

```py
x = [('foo',)] + [('bar', 'baz')]
```

(Obviously I could create a single list initially instead of splicing two lists together in this simplified example.  Pretend that one of them is the result of a function call or list comprehension.)

`mypy` complains:

> ```
> List item 0 has incompatible type "Tuple[str, str]"; expected "Tuple[str]"
> ```

Okay, it infers that I'm adding a `Tuple[str]` to a `Tuple[str, str]` and doesn't like that I'm creating a heterogeneous list.  However, the list is homogeneous from a different perspective; I want it to be a `typing.List[typing.Sequence[str]]`.

Is there a nice way to convince `mypy` of this?  I tried annotating `x`:

```py
x: typing.List[typing.Sequence[str]] = [('foo',)] + [('bar', 'baz')]
```

but `mypy` still complains.  It additionally complains:

> ```
> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[Tuple[str]]", variable has type "List[Sequence[str]]")
> "List" is invariant -- see http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variance
> Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
> ```

Breaking up the expression works:

```py
x: typing.List[typing.Sequence[str]] = []
x.append(('foo',))
x.append(('bar', 'baz'))
```

or adding explicit casts:

```py
x = ([typing.cast(typing.Sequence[str], ('foo',))]
     + [typing.cast(typing.Sequence[str], ('bar', 'baz'))])
```

but both workarounds are much uglier than I'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I only need to add an explicit cast for the first expression:

```py
x = ([typing.cast(typing.Sequence[str], ('foo',))]
     + [('bar', 'baz')])
```

which isn't quite as nice as being able to annotate `x`, but at least it's in only one place.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a static type to your 2 lists? I have tried this and the syntax checker does not complain

```
from typing import List, Sequence

list_one : List[Sequence[str]] = [('foo',)]
list_two : List[Sequence[str]] = [('bar', 'baz')]

x: List[Sequence[str]] = list_one + list_two
```